# Error loading lme4 and glmmTMB in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, lme4

I'm having trouble loading `lme4` (as well as some other packages such as `glmmTMB`, all with the same error messages). The error message is as below,

```
Loading required package: Matrix
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lme4’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/statmod/libs/statmod.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/statmod/libs/statmod.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/statmod/libs/statmod.so
  Reason: image not found
```

My `sessionInfo()` is as below as well,

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/C/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Matrix_1.2-18

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.2  tools_3.6.2     splines_3.6.2   grid_3.6.2      packrat_0.5.0   lattice_0.20-40
```

It was all working fine and then all of sudden this happened, I'm not even sure why or how. Would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stuck with this or a similar issue, this was solved by installing a the package `statmod`. [Please see here for more details](https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-load-certain-packages-image-not-found-error/55285)